# Can CorDapp jars be hot deployed in Corda Enterprise?

Tags: corda, hotdeploy

Our Corda Enterprise server will be run as a Linux service as described in the Corda documentation. Is it possible to drop a new CorDapp jar file into the cordapp directory and have it recognized by the server, or do you have stop the node server first in order to  deploy the CorDapp? As a related question, could you hot deploy (replace) an existing CorDapp on a running Corda Enterprise server node, or do you have to stop the node service first?

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda Enterprise 3.1, hot-reloading of CorDapps is not supported. You have to stop and start the node to update the CorDapp.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you. Do you also have to register a new, or revised, CorDapp jar file using the Bootstrapper, or can you just stop the server, drop the jar file in the cordapp directory and start the server back up?

Comment: You have to re-run the bootstrapper. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609747.