# In Corda `devMode`, do I have to rerun the bootstrapper after creating or updating a CorDapp

Tags: corda

I am running a Corda network in `devMode` using the Network Bootstrapper.

If I create a new CorDapp JAR/update an existing CorDapp JAR, and want to deploy it to the network, how do I proceed? Is it enough to stop each node, add the JAR to each node's `cordapps` folder, and restart the nodes? Or do I have to rerun the bootstrapper?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to rerun the bootstrapper to update the `whitelistedContractImplementations` in the `NetworkParameters`. See https://docs.corda.net/head/network-bootstrapper.html#updating-the-contract-whitelist-for-bootstrapped-networks.